# Reshaping array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to transform the arrays to build a confusion matrix

How can I transform this array

```
array([5, 2, 8, ..., 1, 2, 2])
```

so that it looks like this?

```
array([[5],
   [2],
   [8],
   ...,
   [1],
   [2],
   [2]])
```

Comment: `my_arr.shape = -1, 1` ?

Comment: np.vstack(array) - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> array=[5, 2, 8,  1, 2, 2]
>>> [ [x] for x in array]
[[5], [2], [8], [1], [2], [2]]
```

It can be done with List Comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1009]: arr = np.arange(4)
In [1010]: arr
Out[1010]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

As your title says:

```
In [1011]: arr1 = arr.reshape(4,1)
In [1012]: arr1
Out[1012]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Another idiomatic way of adding a dimension:

```
In [1013]: arr1 = arr[:,None]     # or with np.newaxis
In [1014]: arr1
Out[1014]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [1015]: arr.shape
Out[1015]: (4,)
In [1016]: arr1.shape
Out[1016]: (4, 1)
```